# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED - still not fixed

Tags: android, manifest

New to Android development. Im only doing the Notepad tutorial on the Android site, but I keep getting the error above and don't know how to fix it really. Below is my Manifest code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.demo.notepad2">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"/> 
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name=".Notepadv2" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=""></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Also, I looked up similar questions but it seems people have specific problems with their xmls .. i can't figure out mine since I didn't really write this part of the code ... it was provided by the Android dev site

Comment: Hello, did my answer solve your problem? If so, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that empty activity tag from your manifest file,

```
<activity android:name=""></activity>
```

Comment: Thanks! Wonder why I didn't spot that.